# How can I change the folder SSMS uses for Template Explorer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I would like to change the folder that SSMS uses for Template Explorer to a network folder.

This would allow me to easily share my templates with my colleagues.

Comment: There's a registry key at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\UserItemTemplatesLocation` that looks promising. Haven't bothered testing it though.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith I looked in my registry, and that key does not exist for me, maybe they took it out in SQL 2008-R2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to change the location but you could set up a login script to copy templates from a central location to the default location for the templates.

There is an article [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/System+Development+Life+Cycle/62933/) with one approach. Not ideal but maybe a suitable workaround.

Comment: It turns out that you cannot change the location in 2008.  I've been told that the snippets in 2012 will have a configurable folder location.  Thanks for the website, should work for us until 2012 comes out.